# How do I match only some, not all variants of an enum?

Tags: enums, rust, pattern-matching, match

I've looked everywhere and cannot find a clear cut example. I want to be able to only match some, not all variants of an enum.

```
pub enum InfixToken {
    Operator(Operator),
    Operand(isize),
    LeftParen,
    RightParen,
}
```

So I can perform this in a for loop of tokens:

```
let x = match token {
    &InfixToken::Operand(c) => InfixToken::Operand(c),
    &InfixToken::LeftParen => InfixToken::LeftParen,
};

if tokens[count - 1] == x {
    return None;
}
```

How do I compare if the preceding token matches the only two variants of an enum without comparing it to every variant of the enum? `x` also has to be the same type of the preceding token.

Also, and probably more important, how can I match an operand where `isize` value doesn't matter, just as long as it is an operand?

Comment: **I've looked everywhere** - [*The Rust Programming Language* chapter about `match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/match.html): "The `_` acts as a 'catch-all', and will catch all possible values that aren't specified in an arm of `match`"; this is directly after the intro example, which uses `_`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `_` in patterns to discard a value: `InfixToken::Operand(_) => branch`. If the whole pattern is `_`, it will match anything.

To only perform code if specific variants are matched, put that code in the match branch for those variants:

```
match token {
    &InfixToken::Operand(_) |
    &InfixToken::LeftParen => {
        if tokens[count - 1] == token {
            return None;
        }
    }
    _ => {}
}
```

The bar (`|`) is syntax for taking that branch if either pattern is satisfied.

Comment: This answer doesn't compile, because the enum has four variants and only two are matched.

Comment: @bluss that's the problem I'm working on. How can I include the rest to make it exhaustive but where match does nothing for the other two variants.

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you only want to match one variant of an enum, use [if let](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html)